# Objective-C Pan gesture flicker at bounds of superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a pan gesture recogniser acting as a slider, code as follows:

```
- (void)minutePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
        (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)){

        CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view.superview];

        float leftBound = gesture.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0f;
        float rightBound = gesture.view.bounds.size.width + (leftBound - 60);

        float position;
        if(gesture.view.center.x < leftBound){
            position = leftBound;
        }else if(gesture.view.center.x > rightBound){
            position = rightBound;
        }else{
            position = gesture.view.center.x + translation.x;
        }
        gesture.view.center = CGPointMake(position, gesture.view.center.y);
        [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:gesture.view.superview];
    }
}
```

I have a UIView with the gesture recogniser attached inside another UIView acting as the boundary for it. Its working fine except when I get to the left and right edges. The position variable should not get set lower than half the panned views width but it seems to be updating the view on the screen before the code runs. This causes the view to go outside the bounds and flicker back as long as the user is dragging. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: I found a fix, changed the if else statement to:`float position = gesture.view.center.x + translation.x; if(position < leftBound) position = leftBound; if(position > rightBound) position = rightBound;`

Checking and resetting the position after the translation stops the jumping.